# Parse error in the program while compiling remix

Tags: remix

```
pragma solidity v^0.4.0;

contract Goldbar 
{
  address public creator;
  mapping (address=>uint)  public balance ;

  function Goldbar()
  {
      creator = msg.sender;
  }
//  if(creator.balance  <10)creator.transfer(1);
  event delivered(addressfrom, address to, uint amount) /// by using this function we can track the transfered funds.
//  function transfer(address reciver ,uint amount)

function transfer(address receiver,uint amount)
{
    if(balance[msg.sender] <amount)throw ;
    balance[msg.sender]  -=amount;
    balance[msg.reciver] +=amount;
    delivered(msg.sender,receiver,amount);
}


}
```

While compiling I got a error:

```
browser/Goldbars.sol:16:1: ParserError: Expected ';' but got 'function'
function transfer(address receiver,uint amount)
^------^
```

Comment: You seem to be missing a ';' somewhere between the end of your event command and the start of the function :p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a semicolon at the end of the transfer function as well as after "...address to, uint amount)".

```
if(creator.balance  <10)creator.transfer(1);
  event delivered(address from, address to, uint amount);
function transfer(address reciever ,uint amount);
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to put a semicolon at the end of your event declaration

```
event delivered(address from, address to, uint amount);
```

Also you need to add a space between "address" and "from" in the same event in your code. At the moment it is addressfrom as one word which throws an error.

Comment: Thanks for your info. I have one more compilation error .   TypeError: Member "receiver" not found or not visible after argument-dependent lookup in msg
    balance[msg.receiver] +=amount;
            ^----------^

Comment: Wouldn't it just be balance[receiver] instead of balance[msg.receiver]?